# How to update rails app on production with Docker and Fig with zero downtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, fig

I am using Docker and Fig for my Rails/Postgres app.

What is the best way to push ***updates*** to Rails app to production? Currently I am running the following script on production but it causes about 10 seconds of downtime:

```
sudo fig pull web
sudo fig up -d web
```

I guess the downtime happens when Fig recreates the `web` container.

Here is a `fig.xml` file I use on production.

```
db:
  image: postgres:9.3
  volumes_from:
    - db-data
  ports:
    - 5432
web:
  image: myaccount/my_private_repo
  command: bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb
  volumes_from:
    - gems-2.1
  ports:
    - "80:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

The demo of the app is here: https://github.com/evgenyneu/docker-rails-fig-sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to approach this is to run the app on multiple servers behind a load balancer. Do a rolling upgrade where one server at a time is stopped, new version pulled, and new version runs so as to preserve uptime.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is called ["BlueGreen Deployment"](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html), and is possible to roll out with just one server being orchestrated by fig.

I do this by bringing my whole application up (this includes a Blue *and* Green instance).

```
sudo fig up -d
```

Then, when I want to upgrade to a new version, I change the Green instance version number, and then kill, remove & bring up the new Green instance.

```
sudo fig kill greenapp && sudo fig rm --force && sudo fig -d --no-recreate
```

Once Green comes back up without any problems, I then repeat this proceedure with `blueapp`.

Because I have a loadbalancer pointed to both the Green and Blue instance (with Blue being designated as `backup`) once `greenapp` goes down, `blueapp` immediately starts bearing the load. If `greenapp` never comes back up, then I can roll back the version of `greenapp` and try again. I never have to worry about outage, because I know Blue is pointed to a previously working version, and is receiving all network traffic.

Example `fig.yml`:

```
balancer:
    build: nginx/load-balancer
    ports:
        - "80:80"
    net: host

greenapp:
    image: webapp:1.0.2
    ports:
        - "3001:3000"

blueapp:
    image: webapp:1.0.2
    ports:
        - "3002:3000"
```

Note: `greenapp` & `blueapp` bind to two different ports, and are *not* linked to `balancer`. If they were linked to `balancer` things would get hairy when you tried to bring down one of them, as it would necessitate bringing `balancer` down with it (defeating our goal of zero downtime).